# VS Code unresolved import for local file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a bunch of small Python projects, each of which is just a few files, so I put them all in one git repo.  I always open VS Code to the root of this repo so I don't have to keep duplicating settings and launch config, etc.  It looks like this:

```
.
├── .git
├── .vscode
│   ├── launch.json
│   ├── settings.json
├── project1
│   ├── project1.py
│   ├── _version.py
├── project2
│   ├── project2.py
│   ├── project2.spec
```

The problem is, Python always warns me about unresolved imports for local files.  I thought setting `"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["${relativeFileDirname}"]` would work but it doesn't.  Is there an easier way so I don't have to add every single subfolder like this?

```json
{
  "python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
    "./project1",
    "./project2"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the specific problem you encountered? Please provide us with a detailed example of "unresolved imports".

Comment: I can take a screenshot tomorrow but in this example, project1.py contains `import _version.py` and it’s warning me that it can’t find that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you use the "Jedi" language service in VS Code: (in [settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations))

```
 "python.languageServer": "Jedi",
```

and please use code:(in project1.py)

```
import _version
```

[image]

Comment: I’m not sure what you are suggesting. I haven’t changed this setting, but Jedi is the default according to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Comment: @Elliott B  -Are you using "import _version" instead of "import _version.py"?

Comment: Oh okay you're right!  Somehow my settings.json was set to Microsoft language server.  It works now with Jedi, and there's no need to add anything to `python.autoComplete.extraPaths`